# Terminate $interval on view leave

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework

I have a simply counter running `doRefresh()` in an ionic/angular application, as you can see it is calling itself with the $interval, but when a user leaves this view. The counter is still running. I cant get it to stop running. I have tried many things including the code below. Please help. Thnk you

```
$interval(function () { 
  $scope.doRefresh(); 
  console.log("refresh done");
}, 3000);

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){

$scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.doRefresh())) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.doRefresh())
        console.log("Destroyed");
    }
  });


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) returns the promise you need to cancel the interval. See the following code:

```
var refresher = $interval(function () { 
  $scope.doRefresh(); 
  console.log("refresh done");
}, 3000);

$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){

$scope.$on("$destroy",function(){
    //This really wouldn't be needed, as refresher should always be defined.
    if (angular.isDefined(refresher)) {
        $interval.cancel(refresher);
        refresher = undefined;
        console.log("Destroyed");
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: this returns a bunch of errors. I tried multiple different tries with this code. nothing worked

Comment: would it be better to stop interval based off url? and wouldnt it have to be ionic view.leave or something like that?

Comment: `unexpected token { at line` {{if statement line}}

Comment: Whoops, missed a closing `)`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you @FrankerZ, I should have caught that myself. I assumed it was broken to quickly. Thanky ou